# Unexpected (?) things after changing my account mail address

Tags: support

I've changed today my email to one, which was associated with an account I used before this one and some strange things have happened. The both accounts somehow got merged with a weird result, eg. points on different forums added up, the length of my account here got extended by 8 months, all my tag points here disappeared. This is somehow unexpected... To make things complicated, I was "cleaning up" my different accounts around SE or rather removing all but U&L. Then I changed the email... In the effect I had to remove some of them again. These extra details might help you in tracing back the root cause if you do. This is not really a question, I guess.

Different badges are coming back slowly. Maybe the tags will come back at the day break or whenever they're counted up?

Comment: Not knowing enough about this, I found a Meta.SE post that might help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102392/307535

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks. I didn't even know about the OpenID. Now I see in "My logins" that there's even my Facebook associated and that moreover I've just used it to login, which is completely baffling. All the tag points are still missing.

Comment: I'm honestly not quite sure what I can do to help your situation. Have your tags & badges all returned to normal? If not, I'm going to suggest that we escalate to a Community Manager, as they'd have more visibility and access to repair what's left.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I think a few badges are still missing, eg. a golden one for an answer, which I remember clearly. The tags came back in all extent as far as I can see. I don't really care about what's missing now, but I think you should escalate as this is an evident bug. If it were me to do the investigation, I'd take my old data from a backup and carry out the same operation on a test environment. Then compare.

Comment: I've sent a note to the Community Team regarding your situation. I'd expect them to follow up with you directly, since it appears (so far) to be unique to your situation. The auto-responder to my note said "Please allow for 2 or 3 days to handle this issue", although since it's an unusual issue, I'd allow for extra time for them to research it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When accounts get merged, sometimes the profile with lesser activity also ends up being the new account. The merge process itself instantly transfer all your posts, which updates a lot of things for you, then performs an immediate reputation recalculation.

The process **does not** transfer badges and tag scores, among some other things. If you still qualify for any badges, they will be automatically awarded the next time the cycle for each badge runs. You *can* lose some this way (for example, a question that had 10 score and got you the badge but has since been downvoted will not re-award the Nice Question badge). Tag scores are updated once a day at 03:00 UTC.

Comment: Thanks. This is clear. But there should be some info that changing e-mail to an already registered one IS A MERGE. Otherwise it should not be possible. Just a warning and a yes/no dialogue would be enough.